# Provisioning by stand alone with customization to embedded users

Tags: customization, gooddata

Is it natural to provision stand alone GoodData service with necessary individual customization toward embedded GoodData dashboard users (indirect GoodData users) additionally? Isn't there any worry in such manner to be regarded as duplicated provisioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by *duplicated provisioning* and *stand alone GoodData service*. But, since GoodData Platform is provided as a service, all users are synchronized across all data centers. Let me know if you mean anything else.

JT

Comment: I thought uniqueness in data correlation brings apps variations and differentiations.